# Which of these expressions should I choose: depending on, based on, with consideration to, in regard to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, idiomatic-language

> The date will be fixed _____ your return.

Should I choose *depending on*, *based on*, *with consideration to*, or *in regard to*?

What is being said is that the date depends on someone's return.

Although, none of the above are convincing to me, but I can't think of another expression.

Comment: Is the relationship between "the date" and the date you return *fixed* (i.e. - it'll definitely be exactly 6 days after your return)? If that's the case you could say *The date **is tied to** your return date* - using present tense, because that relationship already exists. Or does *fixed* mean *determined, established*? If so, perhaps *We'll decide on the date **after, following, upon** your return* would be more appropriate.

Comment: The date will be fixed when you return. The date will be fixed depending on your return date.

Comment: Since you used "depends" in your explanation of what you are trying to say, the closest choice should be "depending on". More context is really needed to make a choice between "depending on", "based on" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by the verb *"fix"* but from what I've understood you mean **assign** or **determine**. In such case you could use any of the following:

- The date will be fixed upon your return. *(on the occasion of, at the time of, or immediately after)*
- The date will be fixed after your return. *(in the time following (an event or another period of time)*
- The date will be fixed on your return. *(at the time of)*

Or if we change it a little:

- The date will be fixed when you return. *(at or during the time that)*
- The date will be fixed if you return. *(on condition that)*
- The date will be fixed once you return. *(as soon as, when)*

Basically they all have the meaning of *"depends on"*.

There are other possible ways to say what you want, one of which is:

- We'll decide on the date after *(following or upon)* your return, *(as FumbleFingers commented)*